# find data that corresponds to newest entry

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.2

I'm working on a db via psycopg2, and I want to find the 'newest' entry in the database.
It doesn't seem that I should have to do any sorting to obtain this, as I literally just want the newest.  The data looks something like:

```
 id    |  x  |  y  |               param_a      |      param_b |    param_c
-------+-----+-----+----------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+------------+----------------+-------------
     1 | 324 | 229 | 2013-03-27 22:41:39.052966 |       75.000 |    82.000 
     2 | 317 | 232 | 2013-03-27 22:41:39.185109 |       70.000 |    86.000 
     3 | 278 | 364 | 2013-03-27 22:41:39.203416 |       68.000 |    75.000
```

Let's say that #3 is the newest (it is in this data set).  I'd like to find that without sorting through the entirety of the db as the data set could get quite large over time as data is flowing in through a serial port fairly quickly.

What type of query would I need with the following example code?:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database = POSTGRESQL_DATABASE, host = POSTGRESQL_SERVER, user = POSTGRESQL_USERNAME, password = POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("") #need help here
```

Also, if I wanted to find the N newest, is there a huge difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the best is:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY param_a DESC LIMIT 1
```

Now by itself you are right in assuming that is going to perform poorly.  However if you add an index to param_a, then it can actually do a very quick index lookup and then grab the one record you are looking for.

So your key issue on PostgreSQL isn't tuning the query but tuning the database to make the query run fast.  Simple indexes work wonders.

Interestingly the following performs two index scan lookups on PostgreSQL if available (and the table is big enough, and the data selective enough):

```
SELECT min(param_a), max(param_a) from mytable;
```

So keep this in mind.  This is solved through smart indexing rather than clever querying.